# Axios post in a loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm trying to do multiple posts with axios. When I use the following code, it ends up posting the last thing pushed onto the array i times.

```
  async sendMessage(req) {
    let axiosArray = [];
    const loopCount = req.chasm.attachments.length || 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < loopCount; i += 1) {
      let chatResponse = req.chasm.chatResponse;
      if (i > 0 && req.chasm.attachments[i]) {
        chatResponse.attachments = req.chasm.attachments[i];
      }
      const newPromise = axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: this.serviceUri,
        data: chatResponse,
      });
      axiosArray.push(newPromise)
    }

    await axios
      .all(axiosArray)
      .then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
        responses.forEach(res => console.log('Success'));
      }))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('sendMessage catch error', err);
      });
  }
}
```

That happens the same way whether the async/await is there or not. However, if I move the await inside the loop, which ESLint tells me not to do, `const newPromise = await axios({` it works as expected. I have a feeling that's not the right answer but, rather, that there's a better way to structure it that I'm not seeing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Using async/await is the right practice here. You should modify your ESLint configuration instead.

Comment: You are using the same `req.chasm.chatResponse` object in all your requests.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks; that is intentional. I want most of it to be the same except the attachments.

Comment: @caelon Apparently `axios` accesses the data asynchronously, so they *are the same* with the one attachment you assigned last to it.

Comment: @Bergi I'm going to restate to make sure I fully comprehend. It's looping through all the iterations before the first axios finishes, which means that all iterations are getting assigned the last iteration. I can buy that. Is the proper way to fix it as I did above with `await`ing the `const newPromise = axios({` call or is there a better way to re-structure? Thank you for helping me work through the problem.

Comment: @caelon a) report it as a bug with axios b) if you want make the requests sequentially anyway, then yes `await`ing every one of them in the loop is a good solution c) clone the `chatResponse` for every request

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I have no way of accepting your answer as official but thank you